# Programatically setting ratings with Fivestar/Voting API (Drupal 7)

Tags: 7, rating

I am working on redoing a site with Drupal 7 and the old site has a rating system and I would like to be able to import the old ratings along with the project.  Currently all I have access to is the number of votes and the total score.  Is there anyway to coerce a Fivestar with just these two number or would I also need access to a table showing who voted and when?

Comment: I am having the same issue. I have ratings in a database, collected from a different website and MVC, that i need to import to my database following Drupal Fivestar module standards.